# Unable to do Web Deploy for Visual Studio 2019 .NET Core 3.1 project from Mac M1

Tags: macos, visual-studio, asp.net-core, web-deployment

I have Visual Studio 2019 .Net Core 3.1 Project which can be deployed to my server fine using Web Deploy on my Windows 10 Machine.

But I cannot do Web Deploy on Mac M1 for the same project.. is Web Deploy only available on Windows OS ?

Error I get when trying to Publish using same Web Deploy profile on Mac M1:

```
Build started 3/26/2021 11:00:26 PM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/user/Desktop/project1/project1.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target PrepareForBuild:
    Creating directory "bin/Staging/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/".
    Creating directory "obj/Staging/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/".
Target ResolvePackageAssets:
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.201/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file '/Users/user/Desktop/project1/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp3.1/win-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
Done building target "ResolvePackageAssets" in project "project1.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "project1.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.201/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file '/Users/user/Desktop/project1/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp3.1/win-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.99
```

Comment: The error indicates the build is failing, not deployment. Please include your `csproj` file?

Comment: I can build and run locally fine, but it fails to build on publishing..

Comment: Including csproj file https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrb8ay54f1g1tnu/SWCC2.rar?dl=0